# What is this twin engined jet?

Tags: aircraft-identification

I was barely able to get a shot of this plane so it's not great quality. I was hoping someone could identify it for me. I've never seen one like this.

[image: Mystery aircraft]

Answer (score 11):

It's one of NASA's three [WB-57F](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin/General_Dynamics_RB-57F_Canberra#NASA) aircraft attached to Johnson Space Center in Houston, Texas, and operating out of nearby [Ellington Field Joint Reserve Base.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellington_Field_Joint_Reserve_Base) The [B-57](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_B-57_Canberra) was a tactical bomber that first flew in 1953, and the WB-57F was a modified version that the US Air Force used for strategic reconnaissance. The three aircraft with NASA are the last flying examples of the type and [are used for Earth science,](https://airbornescience.nasa.gov/aircraft/WB-57_-_JSC) and are very versatile as they can fly up to 60,000 feet or higher.

The image below from Wikipedia shows one of the aircraft with pods on each wing.

[image: WB-57F]

<sup>[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin/General_Dynamics_RB-57F_Canberra#/media/File:NASA_WB-57F_(NASA_928)_with_WB-57_Ascent_Video_Experiment.jpg)</sup>